# Exclude results from Linq query excluding everything when exclude list is empty

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

I have the following code:

```
        public IList<Tweet> Match(IEnumerable<Tweet> tweetStream, IList<string> match, IList<string> exclude)
    {
        var tweets = from f in tweetStream
                     from m in match
                     where f.Text.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(m) 
                     select f;

        var final = from f in tweets
                    from e in exclude
                    where !f.Text.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(e.ToLowerInvariant())
                    select f;

        return final.Distinct().ToList<Tweet>();
    }
```

I've been building the tests up which haven't included the `final` resultset and been matching happily now I've added the exclude if the `IList<string>exclude` is empty all items are removed.

So this test passes as it should:

```
        [TestMethod]
    public void Should_exclude_items_from_exclude_list()
    {
        IEnumerable<Tweet> twitterStream = new List<Tweet>
                                               {
                                                   new Tweet("I have a Mazda car"),
                                                   new Tweet("I have a ford"),
                                                   new Tweet("Mazda Rules"),
                                                   new Tweet("My Ford car is great"),
                                                   new Tweet("My renault is brill"),
                                                   new Tweet("Mazda cars are great")
                                               };
        IList<string> matches = new List<string>{"mazda","car"};
        IList<string> exclude = new List<string>{"ford"};

        Matcher target = new Matcher();
        IList<Tweet> actual = target.Match(twitterStream, matches, exclude);

        Assert.AreEqual(3, actual.Count);            
    }
```

but this test now fails:

```
        [TestMethod]
    public void Should_match_items_either_mazda_or_car_but_no_duplicates()
    {
        IEnumerable<Tweet> twitterStream = new List<Tweet>
                                               {
                                                   new Tweet("I have a Mazda car"),
                                                   new Tweet("I have a ford"),
                                                   new Tweet("Mazda Rules"),
                                                   new Tweet("My Ford car is great"),
                                                   new Tweet("My renault is brill"),
                                                   new Tweet("Mazda cars are great")
                                               };
        IList<string> matches = new List<string>{"mazda","car"};
        IList<string> exclude = new List<string>();

        Matcher target = new Matcher();
        IList<Tweet> actual = target.Match(twitterStream, matches, exclude);

        Assert.AreEqual(4, actual.Count);
    }
```

I know I'm missing something really simple but after staring at the code for an hour its not coming to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I know why it's failing: it's this clause:

```
from e in exclude
```

That's going to be an empty collection, so there are no entries to even hit the where clause.

Here's an alternative approach:

```
var final = from f in tweets
            let lower = f.Text.ToLowerInvariant()
            where !exclude.Any(e => lower.Contains(e.ToLowerInvariant())
            select f;
```

Although I considered msarchet's approach as well, the nice thing about this one is that it only ends up evaluating `tweetStream` once - so even if that reads from the network or does something else painful, you don't need to worry. Where possible (and convenient) I try to avoid evaluating LINQ streams more than once.

Of course, you can make the whole thing one query very easily:

```
var tweets = from f in tweetStream
             let lower = f.Text.ToLowerInvariant()
             where match.Any(m => lower.Contains(m.ToLowerInvariant())
             where !exclude.Any(e => lower.Contains(e.ToLowerInvariant())
             select f;
```

I'd consider that even cleaner, to be honest :)

Comment: @JonSkeet, I actually beat you to an answer, the world is ending. :D

Comment: @msarchet: No fair, my wife needed help evaluating a dress :) (And I prefer my answer anyway, for reasons I've now specified.)

Comment: @JonSkeet, yes it's the clean version of mine

Comment: @msarchet: I think the difference in how often the original stream is evaluated makes it more than just a different "version" of yours... it's a fundamentally different approach of evaluating each tweet once and only once.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, yes that's exactly it, mine goes I think '3 times' still whereas yours is only once.

Comment: Thanks for the update Jon, the single statement is what I was clumsily moving towards espcially with the single evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

So what is happening is this:

```
var final = from f in tweets
            from e in exclude
            where !f.Text.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(e.ToLowerInvariant())
            select f;
```

Since the second from is empty, If I am correct the rest of the the statement is not evaluated, so your select is never happening.

Try doing this like this instead

```
var excludeTheseTweet = from f in tweets
                        from e in exclude
                        where f.Text.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(e.ToLowerInvariant())
                        select f;

return tweets.Except(excludeTheseTweets).Distinct().ToList<Tweet>();
```

So that will get a list of tweets to exculde (so if there is nothing to exclude it won't get anything) and then it will remove those items form the original list.